# Laravel apiResource POST request being received as GET request on Heroku

Tags: laravel, rest

I am creating a route with an `apiResource`:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'medical'], function () {
    //Register
    Route::apiResource('patient', App\Http\Controllers\Api\MedicalRecord\PatientController::class);
    Route::apiResource('register', App\Http\Controllers\Api\MedicalRecord\RegisterController::class);
    });
```

```php
PatientController::Class (index) GET
// **return dd('index');**
    
PatientController::store (store) POST
// **return dd('post')**
```

Running on local is working, but when I upload it to Heroku, the `POST` request is returning `dd('index')`

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

fixed by remove `/` on last route